# Amazon Connect contact flow export result difference between CLI and UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-connect

I have followed the [describe-contact-flow](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/connect/describe-contact-flow.html) to export my **contact flow** content using **AWS CLI**.

Here is my **CLI**:

```
aws connect describe-contact-flow \
  --instance-id myconnect \
  --contact-flow-id <FLOW_1_ID> | jq '.ContactFlow.Content | fromjson'
```

But the result is much shorter and completely broke with missing components inside the **JSON** unlike the result which is exported from the [Export (Beta)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/contact-flow-import-export.html#how-to-import-export-contact-flows) feature from the **AWS Console**.

From my point of view, I prefer using command line to help my work to be straightforward and simpler. Are there any solutions for this kind of issue?

Comment: I've tested and your command is correct and should work as expected. The only thing I can think of suggesting is, is your  AWS cli executable up to date? Not sure if it will help, but worth checking.

Comment: @ledge It's `aws-cli/2.11.2` which I believe is quite new because I am using **AWS CloudShell**.